# Encoding coming wrong XML

Tags: javascript, xml, vb.net

This XML comes with wrong encoding. (UTF8 and not UTF-8). This XML is not generated by myself. Is there any way to change from UTF8 to UTF-8 and load it in my code VB.NET?

Thanks

XML: http://developers.agenciaideias.com.br/horoscopo/xml

Comment: You can load it as a string, do a replace and then load as XML document.

Comment: How could I load it as string? (VB.NET)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2